# Kafka, consumer offset and multiple async commits

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand how Kafka handles the situation where multiple manual commits are issued by the consumer.

As a thought experiment assume a single topic/partition with a single consumer. I publish two messages to this topic and they are processed async by the consumer and the consumer does a manual commit after message processing completes. Now if message 1 completes first followed by message 2, I would expect the broker to store the offset at 2. What happens in the reverse scenario? Would the broker now set the offset back to 1 from 2, or is there logic preventing the offset from decreasing?

From reading the docs it appears that the topic 'position' is defined as the max committed offset +1, which would imply that Kafka is invariant to the order the messages are committed in. But it is unclear to me what happens in the case where a consumer disconnects and reconnects to the broker, will it continue from the max committed offset or the latest committed offset?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the transaction features of Kafka in this hypothetical?

Comment: No, but I'm also interested in understanding how transactions would change this behavior?

Comment: They enable "exactly once" processing semantics. Otherwise how you handle your offset commits there's no (straightforward) logic that'll prevent events from either being skipped (at most once) or repeated in consumption (at least once)